# Copy a mesh along an oblique direction and scale

Tags: transform-orientation, gizmo

[image]

I have to copy the rail panel along the dashed yellow lines and then scale it along the same direction in order to create a new smaller panel and end the stairway. I have tried Sh-D / GG / C but does not work.
Also turned to local view. Any chance to align the xyz axes temporarily to that object?

Answer (score 5):

In edit mode in one of the objects already there, select one of the already existing edges parallel to that direction, then go to the transformation orientation panel and click the + button.  This should create a custom 'Edge' transformation orientation, which you can use to arrange things as needed, in new or different objects, or with part of objects in edit mode.

[image: Example of transforming something along Edge Y axis]

To make a thinner rail panel, you could duplicate a panel, go into edit mode, select one of the vertical edges and then transform it along the Y direction of this custom Edge transform orientation - though in this case you can also do it possibly even quicker by using the Edge Slide tool (default hotkey G, then G again, when an edge is selected).  Scaling will not work here as the object is not symmetrical along that axis, and the opposite corners will distort, losing you the parallel lines.

Comment: Hello :). I tried to use a custom transform, but couldn't make it work. I don't have much experience with it, does it work for you in this case? :).

Comment: @JachymMichal unfortunately I cannot easily create an animation to demonstrate, but yes, it does.  It works fine with objects or in edit mode, and stays around as long as I need it for.  You also get the perpendicular axis which can be helpful.

Comment: Hey :). Sorry, I meant using custom transform for the scaling. (That's so me, always reading only half of the full question :D)

Comment: @JachymMichal Well you can use it for scaling and it does scale along the axis - it just doesn't do what the OP would find useful as the shape in question isn't symmetrical along that axis, so it distorts.  With simple shapes like this you can just grab one edge and move along the axis though.  I suggested the custom transform because it allows you to easily *arrange* objects with that axis, unlike Edge Slide, which I would use by preference to just edit a single mesh.  You're right though, if scaling is required this doesn't solve it - but I don't think this problem can be solved by scaling.

Comment: Of course, simply moving an edge! My brain is probably frozen a bit today :).